# Map shows up in emulator but not on phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-maps, eclipse-adt

I create a simple map view that I got from the [Developers console](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) at the android site.
It runs great in the emulator but when I try to get it to my phone nothing shows up. can anyone tell me why this is happening?
Much thanks to all that can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a release API Key for your apk? I believe your MAPS API Key for the emulator is paired with your Debug Keystore in Eclipse.

On Edit: How are you getting the apk on your phone?

Comment: yeah I have a release API Key. should I be putting the keystore in with the project?

Comment: you only need a release key to run outside the eclipse or Debug_Keystore env. As long as your phone has internet access. Thats all I have ever had to do on any of the phones I've tested on

Comment: Hmmm yeah I have the release one. I am just hooking my phone straight up to Eclipse and running the file.

Comment: Swap the debug key back in if your running it as you would an emulator

Comment: so you are saying I should run it with the debug key on my phone?